# Adding a dict as a value to another dict is overwriting the previous value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a piece of python code like below ( I am sorry that I couldn't paste my actual code because its very big)

```
final_dict = {}
default_dict = some_data

for dict in list_of_dicts:
    # I am getting list_of_dicts from a json file
    resultant_dict = merge_dicts(dict, default_dict)
    id = return_value_from_a_function(resultant_dict)
    final_dict[id] = resultant_dict # id will be different in each loop
```

So the final_dict is supposed to have id's as keys and resultant_dict's as values.  My problem is that at the end of the for loop, all my values in the final_dict are same as the last value of resultant_dict. I think it is overwriting the previous values (may be because its a reference). How to solve this issue..?

EDIT 1: merge_dicts actually creates the union of two dicts. When I print resultant_dict, it prints different dict each time, as expected. But when I assign it as a value to final_dict, it is modifying all the previous values with the latest one.

EDIT 2: All the input data is a dict which I am getting from a json file. The final dict should look something like below

```
final_dict = {
    id1 : dict1,
    id2 : dict2
}
```

But I am getting like below ( It is overwriting all the values with the latest dict value)

```
final_dict = {
    id1 : dict2,
    id2 : dict2
}
```

EDIT 3: This is how merge_dicts work

```
def merge_dicts(tmp1, tmp2):
'''
    merges tmp2 into tmp1
'''
for key in tmp2:
    if key in tmp1:
        if isinstance(tmp1[key], dict) and isinstance(tmp2[key], dict):
            merge_dicts(tmp1[key], tmp2[key])
        else :
            tmp1[key] = tmp2[key]
    else:
        tmp1[key] = tmp2[key]
return tmp1
```

Comment: What does `merge_dicts` do? What input data are you dealing with? What should the output data finally look like? Please provide these details to ensure you have a good [mcve]

Comment: I suspect your `merge_dict` function is modifying `default_dict` and returning it

Comment: Can you *please* give actual examples to help better illustrate what it is that is going on in your code?

Comment: Maybe you should store a copy of `resultant_dict`: `final_dict[id] = resultant_dict.copy()`

Comment: You could easily generate a [mcve] for this question. Please do so.

Comment: @idjaw - I have edited the question. Please see if it sheds more light.

Comment: This still isn't a [mcve]. As you've been asked, we need to see `merge_dicts` to have any hope of answering this. It sounds like we probably need `return_value_from_a_function` as well.

Comment: Please read up on *mutable types*. If you want a copy in python, you must create a copy. Otherwise you keep on working with the same object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you generate the `id` first and then straight away assign the merge_dicts value there?

```
for dict in list_of_dicts:
    # I am getting list_of_dicts from a json file
    id = return_value_from_a_function
    final_dict[id] = merge_dicts(dict, default_dict)
```

EDIT: Since `return_value_from_a_function` function makes use of `resultant_dict`, it seems the `return_value_from_a_function` modifies the `resultant_dict`.

```
from copy import deepcopy

for input_dict in list_of_dicts:
    resultant_dict = {}
    resultant_dict = merge_dicts(input_dict, default_dict)
    # I am getting list_of_dicts from a json file
    value_dict = deepcopy(resultant_dict)
    id = return_value_from_a_function(resultant_dict)
    final_dict[id] = value_dict
```

Comment: I cannot do that because I am passing the resultant_dict to a function which gives me the id as a return value.

Comment: Does `return_value_from_a_function` writes anything to the resultant_dict?

Comment: No. It just takes the dict as an arg and then returns an id. Then I have to write the id and the resultant_dict to final_dict.

Comment: The latest EDIT from you worked fro me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to `copy.deepcopy(resultant_dict)` before you put in `final_dict` ?

Normally it solves the problem for me.

Comment: Why would this help?

Comment: Because it stored the actual content not the address of `resultant_dict`, I think.  Try the following `a = dict()
b = dict()
for i in range(5):
    b[i] = i
    a[i] = b
    print a`

Comment: Right, but if you do a copy right before putting it in `final_dict`, that doesn't help. No mutation is being done to it after that point in OP's code.

Comment: There is still a possibility that `return_value_from_a_function` could have modified the resultant_dict, albeit unintentionally.

Comment: yea, then copy it right before `final_dict[id] = resultant_dict`.